# Arabic Font in iOS applications (iPhone and iPad)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, objective-c, xcode

is there any way to change arabic font in UIWebView from html file using javascript commands or functions

Example in english fonts:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var fontType = new Array();
fontType[0] = 'Arial';
fontType[1] = 'Verdana';
fontType[2] = 'Tahoma';
```

or something like that

Any idea ??

even not using javascript or html

pure objective c

please any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it,, by using CSS and integrate it with `UIWebview`